# Empty result array in CollectionType

Tags: php, symfony

Please, can you explain how to work with CollectionType in Symfony?

I have such test:

```
public function testSubmitValidData()
{
    $formData = [
        'collection' => [
            1,
            2
        ],
        'name' => 'asd',
    ];
    $formBuilder = $this->factory->createBuilder();
    $formBuilder->add(
        'collection',
        CollectionType::class
    );
    $formBuilder->add(
        'name',
        TextType::class
    );

    $form = $formBuilder->getForm();
    $form->submit($formData);

    var_dump($form->getData());

    $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());
    }
}
```

After executing this test, nothing is in `collection` part of form:

```
array(2) {
  'collection' =>
  array(0) {
  }
  'name' =>
  string(3) "asd"
}
```

Please, can you explain how to use CollectionType? What should I write for appearing data in `collection` key of result array?

Thank you.

Comment: could you check request data ? And first need `$form->handleRequest($request);`

Answer (score 0):

Try use like this and if you create form for some entity you can use Collection type for some relation

```
            $builder
            ->add(
                'name_from_relation_for_entity',
                CollectionType::class,
                [
                    'translation_domain' => 'invoicing',
                    'entry_type' => SomeType::class,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'prototype' => true,
                    'prototype_name' => 'some__name__',
                    'error_bubbling' => false,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'label' => ' ',
                ]
            );
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I have not got an entity for the collectionType.

I just tried to use like you said, but the result is the same ( The array is empty...